# how to use a ViewPager with more than one array of image?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a listView and I need when the user click on the some item it shows 5 images and when he click on another item it shows 5 different images with the ViewPager.. I don't know how to change the image array that will change with each item of the listView? any ideas to do that?

My code :

```
public class SwipeActivity extends Activity{

    ViewPager vp;
    Table_customSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);


        vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter=new Table_customSwipeAdapter(this);
        vp.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void imageSwipe(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open Link!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}


class Table_customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    int[] image_resources={R.drawable.i1,R.drawable.i2,R.drawable.i3,R.drawable.i4,R.drawable.i5};

    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public Table_customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (arg0==(LinearLayout)arg1);
    }


    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View item_view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_table_custom_swipe_adapter, container,false);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        TextView textView=(TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText("Image "+(position+1));
        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;

    }


    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);

    }

}
```

Here ViewPager it shows the same 5 images..

Comment: Pass the different data set on itemclick

Comment: but how can I pass the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//In your Table_customSwipeAdapter make these chages in contructor get the  image array  e.g 
class Table_customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

int[] image_resources;

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public Table_customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, int[] image_resources) {
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.image_resources=image_resources
}
// In your SwipeActivity while calling the constructor pass the int array
 adapter=new Table_customSwipeAdapter(this,image_resources);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Haroon

Comment: Great that helped Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback interface defined in the `ViewPager` that the `Activity` can implement. At `instantiateItem`, the `ViewPager` can call a method in `Activity` through this callback to obtain the `ListView` position that was clicked. Based on that information it can show the images.

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its showing the same images because here

```
 imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
```

You are setting the same images

First of all you need to create different `Lists` of images that you want to display on each different click in Activity like

```
public class SwipeActivity extends Activity{

ViewPager vp;
Table_customSwipeAdapter adapter;
int[] image_resources1 ={R.drawable.i1,R.drawable.i2,R.drawable.i3};
int[] image_resources2 ={R.drawable.i4,R.drawable.i5};
```

and then in your adapter

```
class Table_customSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

int[] image_resources;
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public Table_customSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, int[] image_resources) {
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.image_resources = image_resources;
}
```

and then pass different list to your adapter from your activity  on each click like this

```
vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    //HERE YOU WILL PASS WHICHEVER LIST YOU WANT TO DISPLAY e.g image_resources1 or image_resources2 or ANY OTHER
    adapter=new Table_customSwipeAdapter(this,image_resources);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. Thanks. :)